# Makefile repeatedly making .PHONY target

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I have a Makefile which looks like this:

```
.PHONY: aws-deps

requirements.txt: Pipfile Pipfile.lock
    pipenv lock -r > $@

aws-deps: requirements.txt
    pip3 install --upgrade --target aws_src/ -r $<
```

If I run `make requirements.txt` more than once, it correctly says it's up to date. But if I run `make aws-deps` it doesn't behave as I expect a `.PHONY` target to, it runs every time regardless of whether `requirements.txt` has changed. For example, deleting requirements.txt first:

```
$ make aws-deps
pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
pip3 install --upgrade --target aws_src/ -r requirements.txt
<snip>

$ make aws-deps
pip3 install --upgrade --target aws_src/ -r requirements.txt
<snip>
```

Am I mis-understanding what `.PHONY` deps do? I want aws-deps to only do something if its prerequisite has changed, ie I have a change in requirements.txt - does anybody know what I'm missing in getting that to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.PHONY` targets tell make to treat a target as not being a file, even though there might be a file that has a name identical to this target. As there is no file named `aws-deps` here, `.PHONY` has no real influence in your case. Instead, make has nothing to compare the timestamp of `requirements.txt` to and assumes that the rule for `aws-deps` must be run. You might change this behavior by

```
AWS_DEP = .aws-deps-done # hidden file to compare a timestamp against

.PHONY: aws-deps

aws-deps: $(AWS_DEP)

$(AWS_DEP): requirements.txt
    pip3 install --upgrade --target aws_src/ -r $<
    @touch $@
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thankyou! :) It's a bit annoying how fiddly this is, but it does make sense. Just one question, why `@touch` instead of just `touch`? I'm finding it impossible to google/SO search for this!

Comment: I'm happy to help :) Prefixing `@` in front of any command in a build rule makes sure the command isn't printed out in addition to being executed. It just reduces the visual noise for trivial commands.

Answer (score 1):

I went through similar case. I wasn't too much of a fan of creating another file .hidden or visible. But that is what I've seen a lot around. I went to the *GNU make manual* [who does that ANYMORE?], hoping that the authors had considered something so obvious. I found the target `.INTERMEDIATE`, which is not expecting a file update. So, your example would be then:

```
requirements.txt: Pipfile Pipfile.lock
    pipenv lock -r > $@

.INTERMEDIATE: aws-deps
aws-deps: requirements.txt
    pip3 install --upgrade --target aws_src/ -r $<
```

It works well and does not require writing an extra file as a flag. I used this `.INTERMEDIATE` target type to print a message before a mass compilation of PDF files and another message for similar mass compilation of PNG files. If you try to use `.PHONY` the compilation will repeat. If you print the message inside the rules block, it will print for every file that is being processed. Printing a one-time message is another use of `.INTERMEDIATE`.

Comment: That's a really nice solution, thanks for sharing it! :)